# Money fractional divide between people and fractions of penny?

Tags: c#, math, currency

I have an amount `$9558.99`, which I need to split between 4 people: 40%, 40%, 10%, 10% . (This is just an example where the problem surfaces)

When I calculate the fraction I get the following results, which all contain fractions of a penny, which is no good, because obviously I can't give a person half a penny.

```
40%  $3823.5960
40%  $3823.5960
10%  $955.8990
10%  $955.8990
SUM  $9558.99
```

If I round up I get a penny over:

```
40%  $3823.60
40%  $3823.60
10%  $955.90
10%  $955.90
SUM  $9559.00 <-- 1 penny over
```

If I round down I get 3 penny less (again no suprise):

```
40%  $3823.59
40%  $3823.59
10%  $955.89
10%  $955.89
SUM  $9558.96 <-- 3 pennies under
```

So my question is what would be the correct approach to fairly divide the amount based on the percentages?

EDIT: This might not be a programming question per-se but I think it's related to a programmer anyway.

Comment: More than anything this is a maths question, not a programming issue. As such - it is off-topic.

Comment: Try posting this question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: why not round down and keep the remaining pennies for yourself (office space style) :D

Comment: Not even a maths question - I think you need an accountant. What do YOU want to do with the left over money?

Comment: You need to refer to GAAP and Eric Evans' "Domain Driven Design".

Comment: Use bankers rounding (default in C#) and dump the remainder. The idea is over time these remainders will pretty much balance out. There is little else you can do.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake I can't because this is a one off transaction between multiple accounts and it's not accumulative

Comment: Ask the end-users how much they care. Compare that to you own hourly salary and start the next job.

Comment: @IvanZlatev even with a 3 pence discrepancy your calculation is 99.9999969% accurate - the only way this would work is by calculating it in italian lira or zimbabwean dollars

Comment: sorry, too many nines in there it is more like 99.9969% - but you get the picture

Comment: @AnthonyBlake Yes I know it's close enough. I will get an accountant to review the algorithms.

Comment: @ShellShock I don't want money to be leftover - it's not possible in the context where the split happens.

Comment: @IvanZlatev over 3 cents/pence?

Comment: I once had a colleague who wasted perhaps an hour on the telephone griping to accounting about exactly this artifact, and how he was being cheated by their arbitrary rules!

Comment: Question directly relates to software development http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/quantity.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Round up, and subtract the excessive penny(s) randomly.

To subtract randomly, pick `n` random people where `n` = number of leftover penny(s).

Intuitively speaking I believe that n will not be greater than 3 in this scenario.

(Alternatively, round down and spread remaining pennies randomly).

Comment: I have marked this as answer, because it makes sense in terms of fairness. However the best thing IMHO as some pointed out in the comments to the question is to ask your accountant given the context of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever rounding method you use, someone is going to lose out.

Here's an alternative suggestion

Person A gets 40% of the total - round to nearest penny.
Person B gets 40/60 of what's left - round to nearest penny.
Person C gets 10/20 of what's left - round to nearest penny.
Person D gets what's left.

A gets $3823.60
B gets $3828.59
C gets $955.90
D gets $955.90